# Is there a way to call an excel file located within a docker container into python?

Tags: python, excel, docker, airflow

I am looking to call an excel file located within a docker container into python. How would i go about doing this? I can't seem to find the correct file path.

What I have done is copied the excel files from a local directory into a existing docker container. I have done this because airflow cannot find files in my local directory. I now need a means for python to find these files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Steven.

Comment: To be clear, the script that wants access to the files is *not* running in the container?

Answer (score 0):

Try using volumes in docker so that you should be able to access the file

Comment: how would i go about doing that? even if i create a volume how would i find the correct file path for python to read in?

Comment: https://devopsheaven.com/docker/docker-compose/volumes/2018/01/16/volumes-in-docker-compose.html    in this link check how to create volume. so that volume can be accessed from desktop too as well as from containar too like mounting it works